# Flutter: Flexible column children inside a SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, layout, flexbox, flutter-layout, singlechildscrollview

I have an app screen with a title on the top, a few buttons on the bottom, and an input form in the rest of the center.

**What I'm trying to achieve:** I want the input form children (i.e. the different input fields) to be spread out on the vertical axis to fill the available space.
When a the keyboard is open and occupies ~40% of the screen, I want all the flexible space between the input fields to shrink, and if thats not enough to show everything, I want the "center" part to be scrollable, so users can find the rest of the input fields, now hiding 'below'.

I'm using a combination of `SingleChildScrollView` with a child `Column`.
The widget tree (simplified..) looks like this:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Title',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.redAccent,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Firstname'),),
                      TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Firstname'),),
                      TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Firstname'),),
                      TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Firstname'),),
                      TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Firstname'),),
                      TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Firstname'),),
                      TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Firstname'),),
                      TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Firstname'),),
                    ],),),),),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => null, child: Text('Next')),
          ],),),);
```

When the keyboard is open, the above code results in this, which shrinks the `Expanded` red container, and is scrollable, so it is the desired result:

[image: with keyboard]

However, when the keyboard is closed I get this:

[image: without keyboard]

So in the non-keyboard layout, I want the input fields to be spread out evenly and take the entire red space.
I've tried all sorts of combinations by wrapping the children with `Expanded` and `Flexible`, add `Flexible` children in between the input fields, and what not.
Could not achieve the desired state. only getting Layout errors.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest you to use an `AppBar`, this way you already have the height to subtract!

Your mistake derives from not setting a `Container` with a fixed height.

That's my solution:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(
          'Title',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, color: Colors.black87),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: deviceHeight - (kToolbarHeight + 32), // 32 => Button height
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Firstname'),
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Firstname'),
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Firstname'),
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Firstname'),
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Firstname'),
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Firstname'),
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Firstname'),
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Firstname'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => null, child: Text('Next')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This wasnt exactly the layout I was looking for, but you comment about having to limit a Column within a Container of fixed height solved it for me.